# C Program that counts how many pass or fail grades and exits when a negative number is inputted

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I'm a newbie to C Programming and we're still starting on the loops. For our exercise today, we were tasked to create a do-while program that counts how many pass and fail grades there are but the loop breaks when a negative number is inputted. Also, numbers above 100 is skipped. This is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
int grade, pass, fail;

pass = 0;
fail = 0;

do {
    printf("Enter grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &grade);
    printf("Enter -1 to end loop");
}

while(grade == -1){
    if(grade < 100){
        if(grade >= 50){
        pass = pass + 1;
        }
        else if {
        fail = fail + 1;
        }
    }
    break;
}
printf("Pass: %d", pass);
printf("Fail: %d", fail);

getch ();
return 0;
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to improve or where I went wrong?

Comment: Your `while` loop is actually a `do-while` loop.  The stuff in brackets after is not part of the loop - it's actually a scope block.  This is wrong.  Also, your while condition is wrong, the syntax of `else if {` is invalid, and you should not have a `break`.

Comment: Note that you ignore students who manage to get a grade of 100 (you should have `if (grade <= 100)`).  This was silently corrected in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put all of the code that you loop between the `do` and the `while` statements.

```
do {
     printf("Enter -1 to end loop");
     printf("Enter grade:\n");
     scanf("%d", &grade);         

     if(grade <= 100 && grade >= 0) {
          if(grade >= 50){
               pass = pass + 1;
          }
          else {
               fail = fail + 1;
          }
     }

} while(grade >= 0);
```

The general structure of a do-while loop is:

```
do {
   // all of the code in the loop goes here

} while (condition);
// <-- everything from here onwards is outside the loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My code is working now. I was thinking I had put the other loops in the while loop. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Note that -2 is a negative number (and should stop the loop according to the specification) but neither the original nor the revised code terminates the loop when -2 is entered.  The condition should be `while (grade >= 0);`

Comment: From the `printf("Enter -1 to end loop");` statement, it looks like `-1` is needed to exit loop, which is why I left it there.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int grade, pass, fail;

    pass = 0;
    fail = 0;

    do {
        printf("\nEnter grade:\n");
        scanf("%d", &grade);
        printf("Enter -1 to end loop");

        if (grade < 100 && grade >= 50)
            pass = pass + 1;
        else 
            fail = fail + 1;
        printf("\nPass: %d", pass);
        printf("\nFail: %d", fail);
    }
    while (grade >= 0);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Here i put your entire condition of logic in the do-while loop. You don't need to use the break statement in this program because there is already a do-while loop.Also , the condition is"while(grade!=1);".

Comment: Hi Khalid, please consider tabbing your code in and also explaining what you are doing to the OP and put your explanation in the answer itself not in a comment below it

Comment: You can also use this codition "while(grade > 0". It is also a very good condition

Comment: Sorry man . I'm new on this site . Next time it won't happen :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help! My code is working now :)

Comment: Indicating how to exit the loop after the prompt isn't helpful.  You could initialize the pass/fail variables instead of assigning: `int pass = 0; int fail = 0;`  You could declare `grade` inside the loop.  IMNSHO, it is far far far better to put a newline at the end of a message and not at the beginning (so `printf("Fail: %d\n", fail);` etc).

Comment: Dude calm down. The student who asked it is just a beginner, he may be confused with what u're saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
    // stuff
}
while {
    // more stuff
}
```

Is mixing 2 concepts together: the `while loop` and the `do while loop` - I'd start by refactoring that piece.

Comment: If the OP doesn't know how to write a do or while loop, then I doubt he'd understand what 'refactoring' means.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what refactoring means. We're still starting on all the loops and I'm a freshman Computer Science student and this is practically the first time I'm coding. I'm sorry. I'll research on this later.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for your problem is:

1. Keep running while the input is not -1. If input is -1, break/exit execution and display output.

   1. Enter grade.
   2. If the grade is less than or equal to 100 or greater than or equal to 0 perform pass/fail checks:

      1. If the grade is greater than or equal to 50, that person has passed. Increment the number of passes.
      2. If the grade is less than 50, that person has failed. Increment the number of failed exams.

[jh314's layout logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18007657/866930) is correct, but doesn't fix the execution logic:

```
  int grade, pass, fail;

  pass = 0;
  fail = 0;

  do {
     printf("Enter -1 to end loop");
     printf("Enter grade:\n");
     scanf("%d", &grade);

     //you want grades that are both less than or equal to 100
     //and greater than or equal to 0
     if(grade <= 100 && grade >= 0){
          if(grade >= 50){
               pass = pass + 1;
          }
          //if the grades are less than 50, that person has failed.
          else {
               fail = fail + 1;
          }
     }

  } while(grade != -1);

  printf("Pass: %d", pass);
  printf("Fail: %d", fail);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I like how you put the logic in order since it looked easier to do and it's more organized. I will do this next time I make a program.

Comment: You're welcome, @ThezzaBaluyos. Writing out problems like that is _very_ helpful when writing code. Eventually, you get to a point where you think like that regularly. I'll leave you with an axiom: "Paper is RAM". ;)